# MySQL workbench says bad handshake

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I tried connecting the database from the server, but MySQL Workbench says that the connection cannot be made and declaring it as Bad Handshake. Can someone help me with this? But if I use the same user id and password and DB connections, it works on the other computer systems. Can someone solve this issue?

Comment: What's the server (+version) you are trying to connect to?

Answer (score 8):

The authentication has changed from mysql V8, you must use a compatible client and server.
BTW it's a bug : https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91828

Here is a workaround without uninstalling the new workbench.
The most probable case is having an old server with a new workbench:

1. get the server version

From a SQL cli tool:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
```

or from a cli connected on the server:

```
$ mysql -v
```

It should show a version < 8.0, in my case 5.1.73

2. Get the mysqlWorkbench for a version <8.0:
   You cannot install the msi if you already have a workbench V8.0, so you have to choose  a portable installation form a zip file here:

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/6.1.html

Select the version 6.2.5 (last before v8.0) zip version

Unzip
Close the workbench v.8 (it lock any other workbench launch)
Launch the V6.2.3 version of workbench, it should works.

Comment: Hi just wondering what SQL cli you are using? Is MySQL Workbench a cli tool?

Comment: @Cecilia No Workbench is a GUI tool, not a CLI tool. The CLI tool `mysql` executable comes with both server and workbench installation, I'm using server CLI installation when I have access to the server. I usually don't need the CLI on the client side, but I use it occasionaly to get or push data dump. just run `mysql` in the installation directory with right arguments

Answer (score 2):

The reason of this warning is version problem. If you have installed mysql server version <= 5.1 and your remote server mysql version is greater than that you will face this problem. I recommend you to install 5.7 or greater in both your local and remote server. This problem will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because of a mismatch in the versions of MySQL servers.
Check the version of the MySQL server you are trying to connect to, and the version you have installed on the computer you are using, they have to be the same.