# on Windows, tomcat connects to MySQL without problems, and when I transfer the project to a remote server that runs under Ubuntu, it does not work

Tags: java, mysql

I've been suffering for two weeks...
Everything works locally on the laptop, the project is running. As soon as I create .war for tomcat to deploy it on a remote server, I get an exception.

localhost.2024-02-11.log

```
11-Feb-2024 12:53:49.771 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
        org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.UncategorizedScriptException: Failed to execute database script; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
```

catalina.2024-02-11.log

```
11-Feb-2024 12:53:27.715 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
11-Feb-2024 12:53:38.232 SEVERE [main] org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init Unable to create initial connections of pool.
        java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
```

On a remote server:

1. ubuntu 18.04 LTS was installed on 22.04, it was still the same error.
2. openjdk-17.0.7 is installed (since I did everything on laptop). I tested it separately to run it .jar on spring-boot, everything starts.
3. I installed mysql 5.7.42, before that it was 8.0.36, there is no difference, it does not work anyway... The base itself is working. I can add users, create tables, and so on, but I can't make friends with tomcat.
4. Installed mysql-connector-java_8.0.11 separately, it is added in dependencies pom.xml (at first I tried without it, I thought it automatically tightens up through pom.xml dependencies, but it doesn't work with it either...)
5. Tomcat 9.0.59 is installed (since I did everything on laptop). The servlet container starts, works, but does not connect to mysql...

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>application</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>


    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Application</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <spring.version>5.3.15</spring.version>
        <spring-data-jpa.version>2.6.2</spring-data-jpa.version>

        <spring.security.version>5.6.2</spring.security.version>

        <!--    Tests  -->
        <junit.jupiter.version>5.8.2</junit.jupiter.version>
        <assertj.version>3.22.0</assertj.version>

        <!--JSON-->
        <jackson.version>2.13.2</jackson.version>

        <!--ORM-->
        <hibernate.version>5.6.5.Final</hibernate.version>
        <hibernate-validator.version>6.2.2.Final</hibernate-validator.version>
        <javax-el.version>3.0.1-b12</javax-el.version>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <logback.version>1.2.10</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.35</slf4j.version>

        <!--Web-->
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <tomcat.version>9.0.59</tomcat.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>

        <!--webjars-->
        <webjars-bootstrap.version>4.6.1</webjars-bootstrap.version>
        <webjars-datatables.version>1.11.4</webjars-datatables.version>
        <webjars-noty.version>3.1.4</webjars-noty.version>
        <webjars-datetimepicker.version>2.5.20-1</webjars-datetimepicker.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>application</finalName>
        <defaultGoal>package</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cargo-maven3-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <container>
                        <containerId>tomcat9x</containerId>
                        <systemProperties>
                            <file.encoding>UTF-8</file.encoding>
                            <spring.profiles.active>tomcat,datajpa</spring.profiles.active>
                        </systemProperties>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                    </container>
                    <configuration>
                        <configfiles>
                            <configfile>
                                <file>src/main/resources/tomcat/context.xml</file>
                                <todir>conf/Catalina/localhost/</todir>
                                <tofile>${project.build.finalName}.xml</tofile>
                            </configfile>
                        </configfiles>
                    </configuration>
                    <deployables>
                        <deployable>
                            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                            <artifactId>application</artifactId>
                            <type>war</type>
                            <properties>
                                <context>${project.build.finalName}</context>
                            </properties>
                        </deployable>
                    </deployables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--DataBase-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
            <version>${javax-el.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-b180830.0438</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Web-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>${webjars-bootstrap.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>datatables</artifactId>
            <version>${webjars-datatables.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
            <artifactId>noty</artifactId>
            <version>${webjars-noty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>datetimepicker</artifactId>
            <version>${webjars-datetimepicker.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-data-jpa.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Test-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>${assertj.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--security-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--JSON-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>



</project>
```

application.properties

```
database.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/topdom?autoReconnect=true&serverTimezone=Europe/Moscow
database.username=root
database.password=root

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
#spring.jpa.show-sql: false

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
database.init=true
jpa.showSql=true
jdbc.initLocation=classpath:db/initDB.sql
hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
```

tomcat.properties

```
database.init=false
jdbc.initLocation=initDB.sql
jpa.showSql=true
hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
```

context.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context>

    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <Resource name="jdbc/application"
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/topdom"
              username="root"
              password="root"
              driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              validationQuery="SELECT 1"
              maxTotal="10"
              minIdle="2"
              maxWaitMillis="20000"
              initialSize="2"
              maxIdle="5"
              testOnBorrow="true"
              removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true"
              testWhileIdle="true"/>
</Context>
```

spring-db.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">

    <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource" enabled="${database.init}">
        <jdbc:script encoding="utf-8" location="${jdbc.initLocation}"/>
        <jdbc:script encoding="utf-8" location="classpath:db/populateDB.sql"/>
    </jdbc:initialize-database>

    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <beans>

        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db/application.properties" system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE"/>
        <bean id="dataSource"
              class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource"
              p:driverClassName="${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}"
              p:url="${database.url}"
              p:username="${database.username}"
              p:password="${database.password}"/>
    </beans>

    <beans profile="tomcat">
        <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/application"/>
        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db/tomcat.properties" system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE"/>
    </beans>

    <!-- EntityManagerFactory -->
    <beans>
        <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
              p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
              p:packagesToScan="com.example.**.model">

            <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
                <map>
                    <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
                    <entry key="#{T(org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings).FORMAT_SQL}" value="${hibernate.format_sql}"/>
                    <entry key="#{T(org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings).USE_SQL_COMMENTS}" value="${hibernate.use_sql_comments}"/>
                    <entry key="#{T(org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings).JPA_PROXY_COMPLIANCE}" value="false"/>
                </map>
            </property>


            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" p:showSql="${jpa.showSql}"/>
            </property>
        </bean>


        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
              p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </beans>

    <beans>
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.**.repository.datajpa"/>
        <jpa:repositories base-package="com.example.**.repository.datajpa"/>
    </beans>
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">

    <display-name>TopDom</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:spring/spring-app.xml
            classpath:spring/spring-db.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:spring/spring-mvc.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

what is the problem? Both tomcat and mysql are listening on the same port:

```
root@vdska:~# netstat -plunt | grep java
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      12139/java
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN      12139/java
root@vdska:~# netstat -plunt | grep mysqld
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11604/mysqld
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33060         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11604/mysqld
```

Comment: have you checket if rhe server is running, look in the mysql error log and see if there is a problem

Comment: is it possible, that "in remote" there is no mysql instance listening to (relatively) `localhost:3306` ?? "normally", you would provide a modified/alternative context.xml for each tomcat (instance/stage/type)   ..it means also not to package context.xml into (war) /META-INF/ (since this takes precedence), but to use $catalina_home/conf/...

Comment: /var/log/mysql/error.log


2024-02-11T11:25:48.209541Z 22 [Note] Bad handshake
2024-02-11T11:25:48.217319Z 23 [Note] Bad handshake
2024-02-11T11:25:50.225304Z 24 [Note] Bad handshake
2024-02-11T11:25:59.615212Z 25 [Note] Bad handshake
2024-02-11T11:25:59.621783Z 26 [Note] Bad handshake
2024-02-11T11:26:01.641134Z 27 [Note] Bad handshake

Comment: root@....:/var/log# netstat -plunt | grep mysqld
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8355/mysqld

Comment: bad handshake!? - sounds relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58392580/592355 ("The authentication has changed from mysql V8, you must use a compatible client and server.")

Comment: the strangest thing is, I looked at version compatibility on the official mysql website
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connectors/en/connector-j-versions.html

Comment: On Windows OS, everything works with the same versions of programs... I just decided to try other versions, but ended up running into the same exception in tomcat. The only thing is, I didn't check the mysql logs last time, but for some reason it feels like they showed the same thing.

Comment: Mysql *very much cares* from which host you connect and therefore you really in a sense have *three* tokens for credentials: a) username b) password c) client host. Are you able to connect with the regular mysql client to the db server using the same username and password?

Comment: Yes. I also created the topdom database manually.
  
mysqlshow
+--------------------+
|     Databases      |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
| topdom             |
+--------------------+

Comment: *database.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/topdom?autoReconnect=true&serverTimezone=Europe/Moscow* that *cannot* be valid for both the Windows *and* the Ubuntu host or do you have two mysql server instances?

Comment: Yes, I have two servers, one on a Windows laptop for test and the other on Ubuntu purchased remotely. And I can't understand if not database.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/topdom?autoReconnect=true&serverTimezone=Europe/Moscow
                    
What should I specify?

Comment: localhost should largely be ok *if* your webapp is also running *on the same machine*

Comment: Yes, it's very strange that it doesn't work...

Comment: And you need to have the same grants on both.